# I don’t understand this,can you explain it simply

Tags: polynomials

What is the condition that the cubic $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ shall have two extremes?

Comment: What is $y=ax^3+bc^2+XX+d$? Could you please check that?

Comment: Sorry,do you know how to solve that? I really need an explanation

Comment: The derivative must vanish in two distinct points, which translates into $4b^2-12ac>0$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that for a differentiable function the extrema points can be found among the "critical points" which satisfy the condition $$f'(x)=0$$ and that for a cubic this leads to a quadratic equation.

What is, in that case, the nature of those critical points if they are two distinct points?