# When does a function: $f(x)=3ax^2 + 2bx + c $ has no solution?

Tags: quadratics

> When does a function: $f(x)=3ax^2 + 2bx + c $ has no solution?

can i say that if the discriminant $4b^2 - 12ac$ is a negative number because according to the quadratic root formula square root portion is a negative number and square root of a negative number is undefined

Comment: Is it 2bx or 2bc? If yes, then you can.

Comment: What do you mean by "no solution"? Every quadratic polynomial has a complex root, i.e., an $x$ such that $f(x)=0$. Of course, for $a=b=0$, it is not a quadratic polynomial, and $c$ need not be zero.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964339/i-don-t-understand-this-can-you-explain-it-simply

Comment: Your answer is *almost* correct ("almost" = you forgot to study the case $a=0$), provided you change your question (and title) to: When does a function: $f(x)=3ax^2 + 2bx + c $ have no real zero?

Comment: @insipidintegrator did I miss something or did you put a wrong link?

Comment: You speak of a solution, but what you give is no equation, it is only a function. You can either ask when $f(x)$ has no (real) root or when $f(x)=0$ has no (real) solution.

Comment: The second answer by PrincessEevee deals with a similar problem. @AnneBauval

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. When $4b^2-12 ac<0$, function $f$ has two complex roots (nonzero imaginary part). When $4b^2-12 ac \ge 0$ it has one or two distinct real roots.